# taking on obligations on

Tags: word-choice

Let's say there is a president of a country who was at the international meeting and he accepted to participate in some kind of expensive project.
Commenting his action, can I construct something like "taking on obligations on sth"

> ...taking on such obligations on the poor country is irresponsible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your sample is the on...on construct.  Instead, you would use

> taking on such obligations **by** the poor country is irresponsible.

or

> **putting** such obligations on the poor country is irresponsible.